# Deploying a specific Git tag with TeamCity

Tags: git, teamcity

At present, I have a TeamCity build that prompts for a %Version% parameter, allowing me to specify a release version for the Git revision that I'm building. This version is automatically built, deployed to our internal QA environment and tagged with the specified release version. Its artifacts are then used by subsequent builds to other environments.

This works well, except that now I want to flip it so I tag the release in Git *myself* and then tell TeamCity *which tag to release*. Primarily to facilitate easy rollbacks to previous versions.

The problem with this is that after TeamCity prompts for the %Version% parameter, I can't stop it from treating the build as a "feature branch," which means that my subsequent builds can't find the artifacts for their default builds (presumably because they are looking for the default branch of the main build, which doesn't exist).

Is there a way around this? Can I deploy a different VCS tag without TeamCity treating it as a separate branch (I have no need for the feature branching feature of TeamCity), or am I going to have to start treating my release tags as different "branches" across all of my TeamCity build configurations?

Comment: I said: "It sounds like you're branching, not just tagging." Ant P said: "Nope, just tagging. As far as I'm aware though the only way to build from a specific tagged revision is to plumb the tag URI into the "default branch" parameter, which works fine until you run a custom build and specify a tag other than the current revision, at which point it detects a branch change and switches to the feature branch. This happens regardless of branch specification. I've already read the docs exhaustively; they fall way short of this scenario."